# Installing PDO-drivers for PostgreSQL on Mac (using Zend for eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, macos, postgresql, pdo

How can I get PDO to work on my mac (os x 10.5)? I'm using the built in php and php in Zend/Eclipse. Can't seem to find useful drivers for it at all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had to install the PDO_PGSQL driver recently on Leopard, and I ran across a multitude of problems. In my search for answers, I stumbled across this question. Now I have it successfully installed, and so, even though this question is quite old, I hope that what I've found can help others (like myself) who will undoubtedly run into similar problems.

The first thing you'll need to do is [install PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php), if you haven't done so already, since it doesn't come installed on Leopard by default.

Once you do that, use the PECL installer to download the PDO_PGSQL package:

```
$ pecl download pdo_pgsql
$ tar xzf PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2.tgz
```

(Note: you may have to run `pecl` as the superuser, i.e. `sudo pecl`.)

After that, since the PECL installer can't install the extension directly, you'll need to build and install it yourself:

```
$ cd PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2
$ phpize
$ ./configure --with-pdo-pgsql=/path/to/your/PostgreSQL/installation
$ make && sudo make install
```

If all goes well, you should have a file called "`pdo_pgsql.so`" sitting in a directory that should look something like "`/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/`" (the PECL installation should have outputted the directory it installed the extension to).

To finalize the installation, you'll need to edit your `php.ini` file. Find the section labeled "Dynamic Extensions", and underneath the list of (probably commented out) extensions, add this line:

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
```

Now, assuming this is the first time you've installed PHP extensions, there are two additional steps you need to take in order to get this working. First, in `php.ini`, find the `extension_dir` directive (under "Paths and Directories"), and change it to the directory that the `pdo_pgsql.so` file was installed in. For example, my `extension_dir` directive looks like:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613"
```

The second step, if you're on a 64-bit Intel Mac, involves making Apache run in 32-bit mode. (If there's a better strategy, I'd like to know, but for now, this is the best I could find.) In order to do this, edit the property list file located at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`. Find these two lines:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
```

Under them, add these three lines:

```
<string>arch</string>
<string>-arch</string>
<string>i386</string>
```

Now, just restart Apache, and PDO_PGSQL will be up and running.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this PECL package: [PDO_PGSQL](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_PGSQL)

I haven't tried it myself, but I've been interested in playing with Postgres as an alternative to MySQL. If I have a chance to try it soon, I'll throw my results up here in case it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will help with the PDO drivers specifically, but you might look into [BitNami's MAPPStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/mappstack).

I had a ton of trouble with Postgres, PHP, and Apache on my Mac, some of it having to do with 64- vs 32-bit versions of some or all of them.  So far, the BitNami MAPPStack install is working nicely in general.  Maybe it will help with your PDO issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

Install new php version via brew and restart server, and php -v, all issues are removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
brew install php55-pdo-pgsql
```

This installs PHP 5.5.32 and PostgreSQL 9.5. I already had PostgreSQL 9.4 installed so I uninstalled the homebrew version with:

```
brew uninstall postgres
```

You then have to update /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to point to the correct PHP version and restart Apache:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.32/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

My OSX version is Yosemite.