# problems installing pdo_psql on snow leapord

Tags: postgresql, installation, pdo, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to install the pdo drivers on OSX 10.6 and I've been following the directions found here:
[Installing PDO-drivers for PostgreSQL on Mac (using Zend for eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747/installing-pdo-drivers-for-postgresql-on-mac-using-zend-for-eclipse/1286153#1286153)

Every time I try and compile the pdo_psql.so driver it compiles fine but the 'make test' finds a problem.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so' - dlopen(/Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so' - dlopen(/Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so' - dlopen(/Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so' - dlopen(/Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/modules/pdo_pgsql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0

=====================================================================
PHP         : /usr/bin/php 
PHP_SAPI    : cli
PHP_VERSION : 5.3.4
ZEND_VERSION: 2.3.0
PHP_OS      : Darwin - Darwin localhost 10.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0: Sat Jan 29 15:17:16 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.9.37~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
INI actual  : /Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2/tmp-php.ini
More .INIs  :  
CWD         : /Users/me/temp/PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2
Extra dirs  : 
VALGRIND    : Not used
=====================================================================
TIME START 2011-04-12 00:35:43
=====================================================================
```

I'm running a 32 bit kernel and my env vars are set as such. After google-ing for hours I'm stuck. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out with my new laptop I grabbed the wrong disk set for Xcode. When I installed the correct (newest) version, everything worked.