# macports apache2 install missing pdo drivers

Tags: sqlite, pdo, apache2, macports, drivers

I just switched to a macports apache2 install in order to get imagemagick.  Now that I have imagemagick, my pdo sqlite no longer works :-(  I've done some research and, of course, the sqlite pdo driver is *meant* to be enabled by default.

Some info:

The error is: `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in ....`

The code is: `$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:db.sqlite");`

Some phpInfo:

```
PHP Version 5.3.25

Configure Command    ... '--enable-pdo' ...

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers no value
```

command line: `php -i | grep -i pdo` outputs:

```
Configure Command =>  './configure'  [...] '--enable-pdo' [...]
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers =>
```

in `/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/.../` I have only `imagick.so` (perhaps I should have an `sqlite.so`?)
Please let me know if any other info would be useful, and I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I tried to solve this referring to the instructions (except substituting sqlite): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747/installing-pdo-drivers-for-postgresql-on-mac-using-zend-for-eclipse unfortunately I got an error when I did a make & install.

Comment: After some difficulty, I managed to get this working on Ubuntu/Debian using apt-get install php5-pdo_sqlite3  No equivalent for mac ports unfortunately :-(

Comment: OK, I can continue to do web dev on my mac by sharing the webdev folder on my ubuntu laptop.  This is a really terrible solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me:

```
sudo port install php5-sqlite
sudo port install php5 +apache2 +sqlite
```

The second line here didn't seem to do anything, but you never know.

After restarting I noticed I didn't have imagemagick, which I thought I already had, so

```
sudo port install php5-imagick
```

Now restarting apache2 the "macports" way:

```
sudo port unload apache2
sudo port load apache2
```

And looking at phpinfo, I have sqlite2 and sqlite (which, confusingly, is sqlite3) drivers enabled for pdo.

Comment: Please don't delete this helpful answer, that I have taken the trouble of writing and posting here.  Note that I have also posted a very similar answer to a related question (that I also asked).  As I have got useful info out of SO, I feel I should post solutions to my own questions when I discover them.