# PHP Installation Yosemite

Tags: php

I believe I have an issue with my PHP installation

When I type php into the command line, i get the following

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Can anyone advise?

I tried this - http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/

Comment: Try disabling/uninstalling pgsql and pdo_pgsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of that post, the issue is with the previously compiled modules `pdo_pgsql` and `pgsql`.

As noted in the comments, you will need to reinstall these modules for the Yosemite's of PHP (run `php -v`).

Steps for doing so with these specific modules has [been answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747/installing-pdo-drivers-for-postgresql-on-mac-using-zend-for-eclipse).

Comment: Thanks @Jason. I haven't been able to get past the first step from that SO page. Ill have to dig deeper.

Comment: I have an article on [Installing PECL and PEAR on Mac OS X](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and I don't use Postgres so I really didn't care for installing PEAR and then autoconfig, etc.

So I found that you can simply comment out those extensions in php.ini

To find the ini file location:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

And then comment out the above 2 extensions in the ini file. Mine was located at: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php/php.ini