# Install postgresql with apache on Mac OSX

Tags: php, macos, apache, postgresql, homebrew

I am trying to make postgresql work with apache on my Mac OSX. I use homebrew to manage all my dev features, so I replace the default php version provided by apache and download a homebrew version, this part works really fine. The problem is when I want to install the postgresql extension..

I have done this :

- brew install postgresql
- brew install php55 --with-postgresql
- brew install php55-pdo-pgsql

And then edit the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file to replace `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` by LoadModule `php5_module /usr/local/opt/php55/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`.

Then when I exec the phpinfo() command, I can't see the postgresql extension installed in the PDO section. I only have this :
[image: PDO config with phpinfo()]

If anyone can help ;) Thank you all !

Possible solution : 
- First install all packets like this : `brew install postgresql php55 php55-pdo-pgsql`
- Then `brew reinstall php55 --with-postgresql`

And it works.. I did this before (maybe not the same order) and it didn't work, I do not know why it works now !

## Solution

When you watch the phpinfo() result, you should see something something like *Loaded Configuration File* and *Scan this dir for additional .ini files *. The thing is there is a global php.ini file and a .ini file per extension you install.
The value for *Scan this dir for additional .ini files * is where the .ini file for the extension must be located. So just need to create a ext-pdo_pgsql.ini and load the extension with `extension="path to your/pdo_pgsql.so"` (mine was `/usr/local/opt/php55-pdo-pgsql/pdo_pgsql.so`).

And for the installation just need `brew install php55 php55-pdo-pgsql postgresql`

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `php -m | grep pgsql` to know if pgsql exists
2. Follow the example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747/installing-pdo-drivers-for-postgresql-on-mac-using-zend-for-eclipse). Jump to note if you have a problem with the instruction there corresponding to number 4 here.
3. Enter `./configure --with-pdo-pgsql="path to postgres"` and return. Mine is at `"/usr/local/bin"`.
4. Enter `make && sudo make install` and return.
5. Add the extension to `php.ini` with `sudo echo "extension=pdo_pgsql.so" >> path to php.ini`. Find the path using `php -i | grep php.ini`
6. That should install pdo driver for postgres

**Note**

It is possible that `sudo make install` doesn't work. It might be due to an OSX feature known as `csrutil`. Reboot your machine and hold down `cmd + R`. From the recovery inteface  run `csrutil disable` from terminal.

Reboot again and perform the `make install`. Repeat same process as in the paragraph above to enable csrutil by running `csrutil enable` at the recovery interface's terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just can't find the directory in the second step. Is it under /usr/local/opt or something close?

Comment: Oh @ThomasCEDRINI. You can achieve 2 by using pear and following this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747/installing-pdo-drivers-for-postgresql-on-mac-using-zend-for-eclipse).

Comment: Well .. I do not understand a thing about what is going on.. I've just done ‘brew reinstall php55 --with-postgresql‘ after installed php5, php5-pdo-pgsql and postgresql and surprise !!! It works ! I really do not understand why it didn't before

Comment: Ok that's good, I thing I've figured out how it works ;) I updated my post